# How to distinct a DerivedCollection's content in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I use ReactiveUI and have a ReactiveList instance. For example, it contains items:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5 }
```

How can I create a distincted DerivedCollection, containing items like:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

?

Comment: You can see `Linq Distinct()`, which will work out of the box for the Integers, in case this is a class, then implement `IEquatable<T>`, then use  `Distinct()`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most performant code but I got this working in a simple Console app

```
var list = new ReactiveList<int>();
IReactiveDerivedList<int> dlist = null;
dlist = list.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, x =>
{
    var contains = dlist?.Contains(x) ?? false;
    return !contains;
});
list.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 });
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dlist.Select(x => x.ToString())));
Console.ReadKey();

// Outputs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

This basically filter the collection based on whether the new element is already there.

Comment: This looks like a Nifty solution to me +1